# Installing dual boot Linux Mint with Windows 10

Tags: linux, partitioning, windows-10, multi-boot

I want to install Linux alongside Windows 10. I have a bootable cd with Linux which runs normaly if I boot from it.

The problem is that Windows 10 by default takes all 4 primary partitions. Because of that I can't install to unallocated space because Linux installer marks it as unusable.

The only possible solution that I found to this problem is making D: drive extended partition and making logical drives inside on which I could install linux. Can someone offer any ideas how to do this?

Disk management shows me this:

[image: Disk Management screenshot.]

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade 3 of the 4 primary partitions. Only the partition with the bootmgr (the active partition) has to be primary, the others can be logical/extended. Then you can create a primary for your Linux.

Comment: I agree with @whs. Linux will require a primary partition, possibly a couple of them depending on your configuration... but most of them will be extended. If its an ssd be sure to leave about 7% unallocated, this allows the drive to move bits of data around and not have one area of the drive get over-used faster than the rest of the drive. Always install windows first and then linux mint second. The grub bootloader has a nicer OS selector.

Comment: Actually, Linux can install entirely to logical partitions. You can convert from primary to logical with `fixparts`, which comes in the `gdisk` package. See [the FixParts documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for details, including some important caveats and limitations.

Comment: Thanks Rod, I didn't know about fixedparts... But without fixedparts, it wants at least one primary partition.... right?